# Calculate area under power spectrum for certain frequency range

Tags: matlab, range, fft, frequency, spectrum

Below I present my code how I calculate power spectrum for my signal:

```
Fs=100;
n = length(x) (in my example always n=160);

whann = window(@hann,n).';
x = whann.*x';

xdft = fft(x);
xdft = (2/length(x))*xdft(1:length(x)/2+1);
xdft = abs(xdft);
xdft=xdft.^2;
freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;
```

Now, I would like to calculate area under power spectrum but only for frequency range 4-6 Hz. The 32 first elements of vector freq look like this:

```
freq = [0,00    0,28    0,56    0,83    1,11    1,39    1,67    1,94    2,22    2,50    2,78    3,06    3,33    3,61    3,89    4,17    4,44    4,72    5,00    5,28    5,56    5,83    6,11    6,39    6,67    6,94    7,22    7,50    7,78    8,06    8,33]
```

So, I can find only area between 4,17 Hz- 6,11 Hz.

Could you advice me, how to calculate area under spectrum for specific frequency range (as I mentioned above for example 4-6 Hz)?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed as follows:

```
idx = find(freq>=4 & freq<=6);

trapz(freq(idx),spectrum(idx))
```

If I understood your question right, what stated above should lead you to the results you wanna estimate.

**EDIT**

Since you don't have spectrum values for `freq=4Hz` and `freq=6Hz`, I would suggest to interpolate values like this:

```
int_spec = exp(interp1(log(freq),log(spec),log(4:.1:6),'linear','extrap'))
```

and then call

```
trapz(4:.1:6,int_spec)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what I want to know is how to calculate area under spectrum for 4-6 Hz not for 4,17 Hz- 6,11 Hz. My problem is  how to calculate amplitude for range between exactly 4 and 6 Hz and then caluculate area for this.

Comment: you may try interpolating data within the range of interest, and then call `trapz` as I did above

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not... When I'm trying to marked calculated area on power spectrum it is quite away from each other. I'm not very familiar with fourier transform, but there is no way to calculate power directly for indicated frequency?

Comment: may you reformulate the last sentence? I was not able to grasp your point, sorry. For better explanation, consider editing your question.

Comment: I interpolate power only for the frequency limits 4 and 6 (not for all range 4:.1:6) and then I put it into my frequency vector, and the result of interpolation to power vector. Now, everything works as I wanted to. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @fpe I'm working through your solution on some of my own data, but curious if you have a reference for why you do linear interpolation on the log transformed data and then exponentiate back. Is there a name for this or a paper/book you that justifies this (as opposed to direct linear interpolation, or cubic splines, or anything else)? Thanks!